# Is there a way to get form values apart from using GetValues?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using `Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];` but i am getting an error saying **IFormCollection' does not contain a definition for 'GetValues'**. Is there a way i can modify it or use another form of getting the values. Below is my code. I am working with datatables and ASP Net Core

```
string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);
```

Comment: If you are using .net core and controllers why not just create a model and all data in your form will bind to it.  Suggestion to you is to read about MVC Databinding.  Lots of tutorials online.

Comment: Can you post your view or page code, please? I can attempt to recreate it and see if I can see how it works.

Comment: @computerGuyCJ I found a solution. Let me update my question